# Talend tMap if condition for mathematical symbol as string

Tags: talend

I have a column in a table and some values has back slash / towards end. i want to remove these slash value and retain the rest of text. so lets say i have a text `"myjunkdata/"`, it should give me back `"myjunkdata"`. However below condition is not working.

```
(StringHandling.RIGHT(row1.CertificateName,1) == "/") ? StringHandling.LEFT(row1.CertificateName,StringHandling.LEN(row1.CertificateName)-1) : row1.CertificateName
```

example data below

```
Certified SOA Security Specialist/
Information Security Management Principles Foundation Certificate/
Check Point Certified Security Administrator  R77/
Check Point Certified Security Expert  R77/
Check Point Managed Security Expert/
Cisco Certified Network Associate Security
Cisco Certified Network Professional Security
Cisco Certified Internetwork Expert Security
Cisco Certified Network Professional Security
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: This is only for the last character being `/` or any place ?

Comment: @AxelH only for the last character. that's it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dont compare `String` with `==`

```
StringHandling.RIGHT(row1.CertificateName,1).equals("/")
```

But you could do the same condition with :

```
row1.CertificateName.endsWith("/")
```

But of course, a regex is always a solution to do this simply

```
row1.CertificateName.replaceAll("/$")
```

The regex `/$` basicly means ending with `/` so it will remove that character if it exist.

Comment: You are welcome @Enthusiast. See the edit, you can use a regex instead of the ternary condition you have.

Comment: Thanks for educating me for regex part. i will accept this as valid answer in 2 minute from now as per stackoverflow rules

Comment: @Enthusiast Regex are nice to remove character like this (and much more). No problem, there is no rush ;)